Changing objects in a Python list according to boolean/binary vector
Let
L=[-1, 3, 4, -2, 6]

be a list and
indices=np.array([1, 0, 0, 1,1], dtype=bool)

a boolean vector. I would like to set the entries of L according to indices, e.g.
L[indices]= an object OBJ, so that the outcome is [OBJ, 3, 4, OBJ, OBJ].
If possible, OBJ should be something such that, when performing its dot product with
any sparse vector, the result is again OBJ in a very efficient way. Something like OBJ=[], or None makes any sense?
Thanks a lot for your help!
I tried L[indices]=OBJ as if L were an array, but i get an error.

what error?  Did you try to understand it?

This is what i get:TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Is it an option to turn L into a numpy array too? Of floats? And use math.nan instead of OBJ?

for i in np.nonzero(indices)[0]: L[i] = OBJ ? Why do you want to use a list? Can't your use an array?

Lists can only be indexed with single numbers. Your indices is an array (with more than one elements).  You need to iterate on L and indices (i.e. a list comprehension).

That 'efficient dot product' bit is unclear. It needs an example.

@ trincot: Objects in my L are large sparse vectors. If is too complicated to get what i asked, I may convert the sparse vectors in dense rows, stack them vertically to make a matrix and use as OBJ a row of zeros, but this procedure looks to me to be extremely expensive. Not sure though

It would be best to provide a [mre] of your actual data, i.e. not integers if you have sparse matrices.

Why does it matter what OBJ is as far as this question is concerned?

@ hpaulj: suppose v is a vector with a billion floats. If i take OBJ=np.zeros(1000000000), np.dot(v, OBJ)=0, but i am not sure whether Python gets to this through individual computations or not. If this very fast, then I may just covert everything to a matrix and use ordinary matrix algebra,  albeit this matrix will be huge.

@ Barmar: yeah, OBJ becomes relevant just if the first part of the question has a positive answer.

With L being a list of OBJ and numbers, iteration over the list elements is the only real option.  If OBJ is the same in all slots, precalculating the dot may be possible.

import numpy as np
L=[-1, 3, 4, -2, 6] 
indices=np.array([1, 0, 0, 1,1], dtype=bool)

[None if b else e for e,b in zip(L, indices)]

results in [None, 3, 4, None, None]
is that what you mean?

yep, that's it. Thanks a lot.

Strange, @mandu, I thought you wrote "I would like to set the entries of L", where here the entries of L are not set.
